# acsess edge database from dynamic ip with app

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, vps

I am working on an IoT project for the storage of environmental variables. I have a MySQL database on a Raspberry Pi on a local network. Now I want to create an app to connect to that database with a help of a virtual private server on a cloud
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9SlD.png).
How i can do that?

Comment: Use a VPN or SSH tunnel. Don't take your chances by leaving port 3306 open to the whole internet.

Comment: I wanna to connect 35 devices    and i cant use ssh tunnel for every one

Comment: For Vpn  can you explain more

Comment: 35 is a trivial number to connect, SSH can handle it easily enough. VPN options are likewise not a big deal. Most can handle in excess of a thousand simultaneous connections.